# Where can I find a database with premade generalizations of mathematical structures?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Last question, I needed to use the general definition of a polynomial which is:

$$a_nt^n+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1t+a_0$$

But I needed to type it all, if I could find templates it would be easier/faster.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: In my opinion, it is faster to type than look for this expression on such database. In addition, you would have to check carefully to see if it is your expression.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can use Wikipedia to get some of these LaTeX-formatted formulas. For example, the following is copied directly from Wikipedias article on polynomials $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$. Just go into edit-mode, and the formatting is very LaTeX-like.